# Check if the current user can write to the registry (C, windows)

Tags: c, windows, registry

Is there a way to check whether the current user can write to the registry? More specifically if it's not an administrator, can it write to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE or the policy keys on HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

I tried with **LookupPrivilegeValue()** but I don't think it's the right thing to do.

Code is appreciated.

Comment: What jeffamaphone really wanted to say was "Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188723 "

Comment: yes, only I have no clue on C#. Can anybody translate that to plain C?

Comment: right, this is not a dupe actually. The OP said C, and, if Jeff and Manni were not aware, C != C#.

Comment: Thanks. Anyone know how to do this in C?

Comment: Doesn't it fail with a meaningful error code when you try to write to write to theses keys, like ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED or something like that?

Comment: The error returned is "Access Denied". Which is OK. All I want to know is whether I have access to write in the registry (for that specific key). If I don't then I'll skip the write.
Unless you know a way to bypass this restriction...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theres one really simple and reliable way to see if the user has write access to a registry key:-

```
LONG err = RegOpenKeyEx(....,KEY_READ|KEY_WRITE);
if(err) {
  // Test err to see if its a permission error. if so, the user does not have permission.
```