# exclude something from foreach loop

Tags: c#

Is there a way to exclude something from a foreach loop. I am reading a bunch of registry keys and there is one folder which has no read permissions so it errors out and nullifies the foreach loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you could check first if you got the permissions to do something

e.g.

```
 public static bool CanReadKey(this RegistryPermission reg, string key)
    {
        try
        {
            RegistryPermission r = new RegistryPermission(RegistryPermissionAccess.Read, key);
            r.Demand();
            return true;
        }
        catch (SecurityException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

foreach (var key in keys){
    if(!CanReadKey(registry, key)){ continue; }

    // do stuff ...
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1188870/6459948) might help you, take a look at it.

If you really want to exclude it from the loop, you could take a look at Lambda where you can filter first before running it.

It would look something like this (pseudocode)

```
foreach(var key in keys.where(x => CanReadKey(registry, x))){
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have try catch block inside foreach loop

Try the following

```
foreach(var i in listRegistryKey)
{
    try
    {
        //Your code


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Handle Exception
    }
}
```

Like this if an exception is handled in the foreach loop and after handling it loop will continue with the next item in the list.

Comment: pedantically speaking this does not exclude items from foreach, it handles items within foreach. I don't know if it is worth saying that or not :)